# Android App Playing Ads When the Location is United States

Tags: android, ads

I am building an `Android` app using the following plugins. The `APK` is displaying random ads when the location is `US`. I am not able to reproduce the case as I am located in `India`. What would be the possible way to find the problem causing plugin? How can I fix that problem? Thanks for your help in advance.

These are my plugins:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'

// Volley Network library
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'

//Firebase for messaging, chat, notification, auth, dynamic links etc
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:16.0.1'

// Green DAO ORM
implementation 'org.greenrobot:greendao:3.2.2'

// AWS
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.6.+'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-sns:2.6.+'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.6.+'
implementation('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.6.+@aar') { transitive = true; }

// For location Fetch
implementation 'com.github.skullper:locationgetter:0.1@aar'

implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)'

//Glide For Image
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
implementation 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:3.3.0'

implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'

implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

// Include all the Twitter APIs
implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.1.1'

// Crashlytics
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.4'

// Mixpanel
implementation 'com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:5.+'

// Expandable TextView
implementation 'at.blogc:expandabletextview:1.0.5'

// iOS toggle Button
implementation 'com.github.zcweng:switch-button:0.0.3@aar'

implementation 'com.github.yesterselga:country-picker-android:1.0'

implementation 'com.asksira.android:loopingviewpager:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:1.0.1'

// Image cropper
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.0'

// Media capture - Photo and Video
implementation 'com.otaliastudios:cameraview:1.5.1'

implementation 'com.sprylab.android.texturevideoview:texturevideoview:1.2.1'

// Days ago
implementation 'com.github.marlonlom:timeago:3.0.2'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
core:3.0.1'
}

greendao {
    schemaVersion 1
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install a `VPN` or `Virtual Private Network` application on your phone and use it to set your location to the United States. Then you can reproduce the error as many times as you would like.

Answer (score 1):

I used AppBrain Ad Detector app to identify the ad service that was running.